# Помогите реализовать через класс

Tags: c#, winforms

Коротко говоря пж помогите есть код который кидает информацию в БД знаю как сделать штобы с формы кидало но хотелось ето в классе чтобы не дублировать код, просто вызвать метод, если можно кодом ответ:

```
 private void buttonSmartphon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Formgolovna FormG = new Formgolovna();

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\UNIVERSITY\ООП\Електронний магазин\login\login\Products.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
       SqlConnection SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlConnection.Open();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(label4.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label4.Text) &&
              !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bunifuMetroTextbox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bunifuMetroTextbox1.Text) 
              && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label7.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label7.Text) 
              && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label9.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label9.Text))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [order] (NameProducts, Price, Count, Username)VALUES(@NameProducts, @Price, @Count, @Username)", SqlConnection);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("NameProducts", label4.Text);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Price", label7.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Count", bunifuMetroTextbox1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", label9.Text);


            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Замовлення успішно прийняте!", "CONGRATULATIONS", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }



    }
```

Comment: так в чем проблема?

Comment: надо помочь очень сильно

Comment: А дважды вы одно и то же (например, `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label9.Text)`) зачем проверяете?

Comment: трудно что сделать? Вам надо код вынести в отдельную функцию? Создайте функцию, перенесите туда код, все входящие переменные передайте через параметры и готово

Comment: я понимаю что все могут говорить мне надо пример как работать по коду, точнее покажите кодом

Comment: не заметил за проверку опечатка

Answer (score 0):

Я ничего не понял, но попытаюсь вам помочь :)

Первым делом стоит создать класс, который будет сущностью, которую вы заносите в базу данных:

```
public class Order
{
    public string NameProducts { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Класс, который используется для считывания, добавления, редактирования и удаления сущностей из бд обычно называется "Repository" (название паттерна):

```
public class OrdersRepository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    private const string InsertQueryText = "INSERT INTO [order] (NameProducts, Price, Count, Username)" +
                                            "VALUES(@NameProducts, @Price, @Count, @Username)";

    public OrdersRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public void Add(Order order)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(InsertQueryText, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("NameProducts", order.NameProducts);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Price", order.Price);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Count", order.Count);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", order.UserName);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Пример использования в вашем коде:

```
    private void buttonSmartphon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(label4.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label4.Text) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bunifuMetroTextbox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bunifuMetroTextbox1.Text)
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label7.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label7.Text)
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label9.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label9.Text))
        {
            // Создание объекта репозитория.
            var ordersRepository = new OrdersRepository(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\UNIVERSITY\ООП\Електронний магазин\login\login\Products.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

            // Создание объекта для добавления в базу данных.
            var order = new Order()
            {
                Count = Convert.ToInt32(bunifuMetroTextbox1.Text),
                NameProducts = label4.Text,
                Price = Convert.ToDecimal(label7.Text),
                UserName = label9.Text
            };

            try
            {
                // Попытка добавить сущность в бд.
                ordersRepository.Add(order);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Если добавить не получилось, то вы водим ошибку.
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка", ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Замовлення успішно прийняте!", "CONGRATULATIONS", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            // Если форма не прошла валидацию
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка", "Некорректные данные", MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: спасибо большое за чудесный ответ помогли на прримере кода понятней намного